# Running a query from Django ModelForm

Tags: python, sql, django

I have the following existing code to work with (I included just the relevant parts).

models.py

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    customer_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=16)
    account_phone = PhoneNumberField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=255)
    display_phone = PhoneNumberField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=255)
    .
    .
    .
```

customer.py

```
@render_to('customer/edit.html')
def edit(request, customer_id):
    customer = Customer.objects.get(customer_id=customer_id)
    if not request.POST:
        return dict(form=CustomerForm(instance=customer))
    submit = request.POST.copy()
    submit['customer_id'] = customer.customer_id
    form = CustomerForm(submit, instance=customer)
    if not form.is_valid():
        return dict(form=form)
    _f = form.save(commit=False)
    _f.save()

class CustomerForm(ModelForm):
    .
    .
    .
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        super(CustomerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        .
        .
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
```

I need to add a query to the CustomerForm called something like `assigned_numbers` that will allow me to get the phone numbers from `account_phone` and `display_phone` that are associated with the `customer_id`.  I am getting stuck on how to run the query correctly and would greatly appreciate any suggestions.  If I need to provide more information, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form is a model form for `customer`, so it will have fields for `account_phone` and `display_phone` already unless you've specified the fields in a way that excludes them.

If you need to do something with them besides just have fields for them that start populated according to your customer instance, you can access `form.instance.account_phone` or whatever.

If for some reason it's more convenient, in your `__init__` method,  you can access `instance` from `kwargs` to look up the values.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    super(CustomerForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    if 'instance' in kwargs:
        self.assigned_numbers = (instance.account_phone, instance.display_phone)
```